# How to create dynamic select list in form using FAPI

Tags: 7, forms

I am using Drupal 7. I have created two form (FAPI) fields of type `select` , State and District.
The district field should contain the dynamic options based on the state selected.

State field:

```
 $form['state'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Name of your State:') ,
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#default_value' => array(
  ),
  '#options' => $options,
  '#required' => '1',
  );
```

District field:

```
 $form['district'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Name of your District:') ,
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#default_value' => array(
  ),
  '#options' => district_list($form_state['values']['state']), // district_list is the function which will return the list of district based on name of state passed.
  '#required' => '1',
  );
```

The above code doesn't work, is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: Yes - the code to make your form element dynamic. What led you to believe what you've got would make an AJAX-enabled, dynamic select list group? I ask because whatever documentation, tutorial, example or question/answer you're following is way off and needs to be corrected

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the #ajax property in your State select list, with a callback function that returns the district element.  So something like this:

```
$form['state'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Name of your State:') ,
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#default_value' => array(
   ),
  '#options' => $options,
  '#required' => '1',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'MY_MODULE_state_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'edit-district',
 );
```

then create a callback called `MY_MODULE_state_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state)`
and within the function,

```
MY_MODULE_state_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    return $form['district'];
}
```

It may be slightly more complicated than this, based on your use-case, but this is the meat of it.